# MPI_Put for distributed data

Tags: c, mpi, distributed-computing, openmpi, mpi-rma

I am trying to use MPI-2 features for one sided communication to write a program for distributed hash table. Each process exposes a memory (B) to all others at the start. Then, hopefully, each process can access the other's memory without synchronization. So far what I have is shown below ( a modified code from an example http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Put.html ) . At the end, I get wrong values for B[99] in some cases (differs from run to run). What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit: I fixed the above problem now with a wait call at the end, but I want to wait for completion of each MPI_Get call. But it looks like the only option is an MPI_Win_fence which requires global synchronization, or MPI_Win_start/MPI_Win_complete for each MPI_Get call. Is it possible to call the latter once as shown below and somehow be able to wait after each MPI_Get call?

```
#include "mpi.h" 
#include "stdio.h"

#define SIZE2 200

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
int rank, nprocs, *B;
MPI_Group comm_group;
MPI_Win  winl;


MPI_Init(&argc,&argv); 
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&nprocs); 
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank); 

MPI_Alloc_mem(SIZE2 * sizeof(int), MPI_INFO_NULL, &B);
for(int i=0; i<SIZE2; i++)  B[i] = 0;

MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_group);
MPI_Win_create(B, SIZE2*sizeof(int), sizeof(int),MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &winl);
MPI_Win_post(comm_group, 0, winl);
MPI_Win_start(comm_group, 0, winl);
if(rank == 0)
{
    int drank = (rank == 0) ? 1 : 0;
    int value = 200, value1;
    int index = 99;
    MPI_Get(&value1, 1, MPI_INT, drank, index+1, 1, MPI_INT, winl); 
    MPI_Put(&value, 1, MPI_INT, drank, index, 1, MPI_INT, winl); 

    MPI_Get(&value1, 1, MPI_INT, drank, index+1, 1, MPI_INT, winl); 
    MPI_Put(&value, 1, MPI_INT, drank, index, 1, MPI_INT, winl); 
}

MPI_Win_complete(winl);
MPI_Win_wait(winl);
printf("%d: %d %d\n",rank,B[99],B[100]);

MPI_Group_free(&comm_group);
MPI_Win_free(&winl); 
MPI_Free_mem(B);
MPI_Finalize();

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem. What MPI implementation are you using? On what platform? How do you start the MPI job? Could you give examples of right and wrong output?

Comment: It looks like the problem was run-time dependent. I have fixed that now but have another problem with completing each MPI_Get operation before proceeding. Do you know how to fix it?